# Abstract properties or base constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, properties, abstract-class

Which method should I prefer and why? Is there any real difference?

Abstract property:

```
abstract class Table
{
    public abstract string Title { get; }
}

class InfoTable : Table
{
    public override string Title
    {
        get { return "Info"; }
    }
}
```

or base class constructor parameter:

```
abstract class Table
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public Table(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}

class InfoTable : Table
{
    public InfoTable() : base("Info") { }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately question which make people argue over aren't well accepted here, this question is gonna be closed fast

Comment: @FabioMarcolini How to rephrase? I need answer!

Comment: there's no real answer to this question, it's just a matter of what you need this for

Comment: well, "no difference" - is one of the possible answers (see edited question). I'm not sure

Comment: I would prefer the first one at least if in another class the title must not be hardcoded you can do that, but as it stand either way make little sense to me

Comment: @FabioMarcolini Didn't get what you mean. Can you show?

Comment: Very good question for me, it needs a reopening.

Answer (score 1):

As they stand your class are just data class which is not a good OOP practice.
Anyway I prefer the first type because if in that case in a subclass you can have a non harcoded title as in this example

```
class InfoTable : Table
{
    private string id;
    private string name;
    public override string Title
    {
        get { return name+id; }
    }
}
```

but still it may depend which of the two is better

Okay let's say that the class is not something as static as this example then

```
private DynamicTitleProvider provider;
public override string Title
    {
        get { return provider.GetTitle(); }
    }
```

Comment: public InfoTable(string name, string id) : base(name + id) { }